# ORDER BY a concatenated name in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, concatenation

I have a table called USERS from which I'm getting an employee's first and last name, and printing them out as one name. How do I use ORDER BY correctly on this data?

Here's what I have:

```
SELECT l.OFFICE_NAME, (us.LAST_NAME || ' , ' || us.FIRST_NAME) AS "Employee Name"
FROM LOCAL_OFFICE l, USERS us
WHERE l.LOCAL_OFFICE_ID = us.LOCAL_OFFICE_ID
ORDER BY  l.OFFICE_NAME  --what do I place here?--
```

I will do this through a JOIN instead of the more expensive FROM, but  how do I order by the name alphabetically?

Comment: FROM is not "more expensive" than JOIN.  JOIN is just preferred these days as it is clearer to read, particularly in large SQL statements.

Comment: @Tony Andrews  Ah. I'm teaching this to myself, and read somewhere that FROM is essentially a cartesian product of the two tables, which I know can be incredibly expensive.

Comment: No, it is a Cartesian product only if you don't supply a join condition in the WHERE clause, which you have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can say:

```
ORDER BY office_name, "Employee Name"
```

That works in 11G, but maybe not in older version of Oracle.

Comment: I tried this, but I get an error: [Error] Execution (11: 10): ORA-00904: "Employee Name": invalid identifier

Comment: Oh I found an error somewhere else that was causing it. It works now, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
ORDER BY l.OFFICE_NAME, (us.LAST_NAME || ' , ' || us.FIRST_NAME)
```

Answer (score 5):

As your concatenation isn't really adding anything new, why not just

```
ORDER BY l.OFFICE_NAME, us.LAST_NAME, us.FIRST_NAME
```

Edit: If there are indexes on `USERS.LAST_NAME` and / or `USERS.FIRST_NAME`, this will be faster than ordering by a concatenation result

Comment: This works, I didn't know if there was something required because I'm referencing the concat AS "Employee Name"

Comment: Like this one a lot more. Gives the chance to make indexes worthy.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

ORDER BY 1,2

This is not fantastically good practice, but it works.